# NetworkManager show wifi as unavailable but there is connection with saved network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, thinkpad, x230

I have a problem with NetworkManager on Ubuntu 19.04 with Cinnamon environment installed on ThinkPad x230, it still shows that Wireless is unavailable but there is already set. Also there is possibility to manage wifi card using `iwlist` and output of `$ nmcli radio` is:

```
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN   
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

And some additional details:

```
# rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
# lshw -class network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 34
       serial: a4:4e:31:b3:f7:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-20-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.249 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:f1c00000-f1c01fff
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

EDIT:

Connection that works is not listen in NetworkManager's system-connections, everything work fine on Ubuntu 19.04 live usb, on this installation works fine external usb wifi card.

EDIT2:

I have found those lines in logs of Network Manager

```
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200032.2191] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200032.2214] bluez5: NAP: added interface 3C:77:E6:F0:A6:D8
NetworkManager[16749]: <error> [1563200032.4465] sup-iface[0x559da7c0c930,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200032.4466] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200032.4468] manager: startup complete
NetworkManager[16749]: <warn>  [1563200042.6966] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#1).
NetworkManager[16749]: <error> [1563200042.8414] sup-iface[0x559da7c0ca10,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200042.8414] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
NetworkManager[16749]: <warn>  [1563200052.6917] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#2).
NetworkManager[16749]: <error> [1563200052.8182] sup-iface[0x559da7c0caf0,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200052.8183] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
NetworkManager[16749]: <warn>  [1563200062.6967] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
NetworkManager[16749]: <error> [1563200062.8134] sup-iface[0x559da7c0cbd0,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200062.8135] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
NetworkManager[16749]: <warn>  [1563200072.6986] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#4).
NetworkManager[16749]: <error> [1563200072.8372] sup-iface[0x559da7c0ccb0,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200072.8372] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
NetworkManager[16749]: <warn>  [1563200082.6926] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
NetworkManager[16749]: <error> [1563200082.8015] sup-iface[0x559da7c0cd90,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200082.8016] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
NetworkManager[16749]: <info>  [1563200082.8016] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
```

EDIT3:
**I reinstalled whole system and it works now.**

Comment: maybe related, do `sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service` https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1199616

Comment: I can't check it anymore, I reinstalled Ubuntu and it works already